# How to extract the first and last element

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

It is a elemental question maybe,but I am confusing still.If I have a 1-dimension list `list`

```
a = Range[5]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```

So I can do this to get the first and last element:

```
a[[{1, -1}]]
(* {1, 5} *)
```

But when I have a matrix `mat`,why I cannot do this with same method?

```
mat = Partition[Range[12], 4];
mat[[{{1, 1}, {-1, -1}}]]
```

This expression will put some error information.

#### Question

1. Did I make any grammatical mistakes?
2. Can we use any elegant method to get this two elements?

Comment: You can use Extract with similar syntax, I believe.

Comment: You can use `mat[[1,1]]` and `mat[[-1,-1]]`. Or to use same syntax as 1D example, can Flatten the matrix first.

Comment: @march Good point out,just little pitty,we cannot asign it by same syntax `Extract[mat,{{1,1},{-1,-1}}]={c,d}`.This is my purpose actually.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks advice,which is a good suggestion.

Comment: I find using `[[x,y]]` much easier and more common with other languages (Matlab, etc...) than having to call functions to do it

Comment: if you really wanted the assignment you should have made that the question..  You can use `ReplacePart` although it oddly doesn't take quite the same "list of positions" syntax as `Extract`.  Ive done this: `mat = ReplacePart[mat, MapThread[Rule, #]] &@{{{1, 1}, {-1, -1}}, {a, 
    b}}`

Answer (score 3):

Does the following help:

```
mat = Partition[Range[12], 4];
{#[[1, 1]], #[[-1, -1]]} & @ mat
```

Or, alternatively,

```
{First@First@#, Last@Last@#} & @ mat
```

Comment: suspect you are looking for something different than the following. 
    mat[[1, 1]] = a;
    mat[[-1, -1]] = b;
    mat // TableForm

Comment: @Thanks, :)If we just extract,we can use `{First@#, Last@#} &@Flatten[mat]` or `Through[{First,Last}[Flatten[mat]]]`