# How to change the first value and last value in a matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I try to simplify my encounter,so I post a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134323/21532).But I aware that turn a unexpected direction.I try to *re-assign* the first and last element in a matix,such as I have:

```
mat={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}}
```

How to get with a *concise* method?

```
{{a,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,b}}
```

And I try to use `mat[[{{1,1},{-1,-1}}]]={a,b}` to get what I want,I get some error information,despite I think I have not made syntax error.

Comment: `list[[1, 1]] = a; list[[-1, -1]] = b` keep it simple :)

Comment: `(list[[Sequence @@ First@#]] = Last@#) & /@ {{{1, 1}, a}, {{-1, -1}, 
   b}}; list`

Comment: @Nasser Thanks. :)

Comment: @Edmund Thanks,too :)

Comment: `mat[[{{1,1},{-1,-1}}]]` is in fact a syntax error.  It does not correspond to any case listed in the documentation.  If you remove the outer braces, you get a permissible expression, but not what you are seeking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could always do this with `ReplacePart` although you have to reassign `mat` altogether:

```
In[50]:= mat = ReplacePart[mat, {{1, 1} -> a, {-1, -1} -> b}]

Out[50]= {{a, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, b}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Also

```
indices = {{1, 1}, {-1, -1}};
vals = {a, b};

mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
(mat[[##]] = vals[[#]]) & @@@indices; mat
```

> {{a, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, b}}

Or

```
mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
mat = Block[{i = 1}, MapAt[vals[[i++]] &, mat, indices]]; mat
```

> {{a, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, b}}

Or

```
mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
(mat[[## & @@ #]] = #2) & @@@ Transpose[{indices, vals}]; mat
```

> {{a, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, b}}

Answer (score 3):

```
mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
```

Since V 12.2 there is `ApplyTo` (//=):

Borrowing `ReplacePart` from @b3m2a1

```
mat //= ReplacePart[{{1, 1} -> a, {-1, -1} -> b}];
```

{{a, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, b}}

Compare this with

```
mat = ReplacePart[mat, {{1, 1} -> a, {-1, -1} -> b}];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `SubsetMap`:** (introduced April 16, 2019)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};

SubsetMap[{a, b} &, mat, {{1, 1}, {-1, -1}}]
```

> {{a, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, b}}

Comment: Since the user wants to change mat, `mat = ...` would be more appropriate. Also possible: `mat //= SubsetMap[{a, b} &, {{1, 1}, {-1, -1}}]`. Sorry for this pedantic remark, +1 otherwise.

Comment: Thanks@eldo for catching this.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ReplaceAll`:

```
mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};

mat /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {Join[{a}, x[[2 ;;]]], y, Join[z[[1 ;; -2]], {b}]}

(*{{a, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, b}}*)
```

Also, constructing a function:

```
f = # /. (# /. x : {__List} :> {x[[1]] -> {a}~Join~x[[1, 2 ;;]], 
    x[[-1]] -> x[[-1, 1 ;; -2]]~Join~{b}}) &;

f@mat

(*{{a, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, b}}*)
```